# Is the appearance of "Action Not Found" and a list of tried URIs a security concern in Play?

Tags: http

The [Routing in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting) documentation has been read and multiple code samples have been run including [this one](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-simple-oauth). When one navigates to an unknown URI it returns a list of tried URIs:

[image]

**Expected outcome**

The expectation was that no information would have been returned when one navigates to an unknown URI or is unauthorized or forbidden like in [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httpd.html). No matter what URI one tries, the unauthorized message is always returned and no information regarding tried URIs is shown:

[image]

**Question**

Is the appearance of "Action Not Found" and a list of tried URIs a security concern in Play?

Comment: Did you start the application with `play run`?

Comment: @StefanBraun At the of writing I started it with `run` instead of `start`. The latter does not return the list of possible URIs.